# how can i print the number of array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am trying to print that in cmath:

```
Enter a number between 1 and 10:  
4 
Enter the sides of triangle 1: 
3 3 3 
Enter the sides of triangle 2: 
3 4 5 
Enter the sides of triangle 3: 
3 4 5 
Enter the sides of triangle 4: 
3 2 3 
Area of triangle 4: 2.83 
Area of triangle 1: 3.90 
Area of triangle 2: 6.00 
Area of triangle 3: 6.00
```

I can finish other part of question, but I don't really know how to print the number order of the array like the last part. I jam there for a long time.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, a, b, c, n, temp = 0;
    double s, ar, area[10];
    cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 10: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the sides of triangle " << (i + 1);
        cout << ":" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
        cin >> c;
        s = (a + b + c) / 2;

        ar = pow((s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)), 0.5);
    
        area[i] = ar;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (area[i] > area[j])
            {
                temp = area[i];
                area[i] = area[j];
                area[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Area of triangle "<< i << ":" << area[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like the code to help me do the sorting in C++.

Comment: One problem: `temp` is an *int*. Think about that and how you use it in your sorting

Comment: And `(a + b + c) / 2` is an *integer* operation, without decimals.

Comment: Other than those problems, what *is* the problem you're having? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it, like actually ask us a question.

Comment: You should probably have index array for the sort (or a class `indexedTriangle`), (to allow to match index and area/triangle).

Comment: If your only problem is sorting, look up std::sort

Comment: thank you guys comment i will read those and try to fix my code

Comment: What does "the number of array" even mean?

Comment: the order of each triangle  type in

Comment: First, replace ```s = (a + b + c) / 2;``` with ```s = (a + b + c) / 2.0;```. Second, sort the area array by ```std::sort(area.begin(), area.end());```.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is that you need to keep track on the areas **AND** the indices. So, you can simply create a second array and fill this with indices from 0...9.

Then later during the sorting, you will compare the areas, BUT exchange the values in the index array. And not swap any area data in oyur bubble sort.

For the comparison and output you need then a double indirection. See below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, a, b, c, n, temp = 0;
    double s, ar, area[10];
    int index[10];

    cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 10: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the sides of triangle " << (i + 1);
        cout << ":" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
        cin >> c;
        s = (a + b + c) / 2;

        ar = pow((s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)), 0.5);

        area[i] = ar;
        index[i] = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (area[index[i]] > area[index[j]])
            {
                temp = index[i];
                index[i] = index[j];
                index[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Area of triangle " << index[i]+1 << ":\t" << area[index[i]] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```